# Map kit does not show on the cell phone

Tags: cordova, huawei-mobile-services, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to implement the huawei map kit with quasar and cordova but I don't know why it doesn't work. I am following the documentation step by step, adding the methods and dependencies that are needed but still the map is not displayed. Annex my code

```
<template>
<div id="my-map-view"></div>
</template>

export default {
 methods: {
 async createMapView() {
  
  const mapInstance = await HMSMap.create("my-map-view", {
    zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
    zoomControlsEnabled: true,
    cameraPosition: {
      target: { lat: 39.707187, lng: 37.530353 },
      zoom: 7
    }
  });
}
},
mounted() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", async () => {
 
  await HMSMap.init();
  
  this.createMapView();
  
});
}
};
```

if someone has a reference code it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Maybe div has no width and height properties. Try setting them in CSS:

```
css
#my-map-view {
  width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Otherwise logs or a minimal example that reproduces the issue is needed.